# jquery and php form validation

Tags: jquery

I am validating a form using PHP like this (part of it):

```
if (!($email)){
echo "<br />
<br />
<span class=\"difftext\">Please enter your E-mail!</span>";
exit();
}
```

Is there a way, by using Jquery, to display the msg without refresh my page or do I have to use totally Jquery validation?

Thank you

EDIT...

```
('#chkout', 'submit', function(){
   $.ajax({
     type: 'post',
     url: 'help_scripts/prcd_chkout_ondelivery.php',
     data: 'data',
     success: function (){
     $('#cust_order_result').html('data');
     }
 })
 return false;
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup an **AJAX call** using JQuery.  The AJAX call will allow you to do the server side verification **without doing a page refresh.**

Look up [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) and [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) in the JQuery manual to try to structure cod which will work for your case.

Answer (score 2):

You can validate the form before it is submitted using jQuery. Just keep in mind that client-side form validation in no replacement for server-side form validation and you still need to use it too.

Comment: So I have to validate by using Jquery... I wished to find a way for it :) Never mind. Thank you

Comment: What I was saying is that you should keep you PHP form validation, even after you add jQuery form validation. It's important to have some sort of validation on your server.

Comment: @Pavlos1316 We need to see the form field you are trying to validate before we can tell you how to validate it in jQuery

Comment: Yes I understood that... And I will... My problem is the msg display thus I will have to use Jquery.

Answer (score 2):

There are two choices: 
1) Interrupt the submit process to check for values in your desired input fields using Javascript / JQuery, and allow submission when validation passes.

2) Still use PHP to do the validation, but submit the form using an AJAX call and use the PHP script to set up the cases for successful and unsuccessful validation.

The actual process will vary depending on which one of these two choices you want to use.

Comment: Would something like the above edit work??? Is it something like that I need? (your 2nd way?)

Comment: that looks like it will work, for sure. EDIT: apologies for the delayed reply!